# Borel hierarchy doesn't "collapse" before $\omega_1$

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

I know that $\bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_1} \Sigma_\alpha^0 = \mathcal{B}(X)$ for any Polish space $X$, but I want to know if it's really necessary to take the union for every ordinal less than $\omega_1$. Is there an example of a Polish space where $\bigcup_{\alpha < \beta} \Sigma_\alpha^0 \varsubsetneq \mathcal{B}(X)$ for every countable ordinal $\beta$? What's the case of $\mathbb{R}$ or $[0, 1]$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct term is "stabilize" rather than" collapse".

Answer (score 15):

To complement Yann's answer: This is a nice problem, the possible length of Borel hierarchies in different spaces or without assuming the axiom of choice. It has been studied in detail by Arnie Miller. See

> Arnold W. Miller. [*On the length of Borel hierarchies*](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Eawmille1/res/hier.pdf), Ann. Math. Logic, **16 (3)**, (1979), 233–267. [MR0548475 (80m:04003)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=548475),
>
> Arnold W. Miller. [*Long Borel hierarchies*](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Eawmille1/res/longbor.pdf), MLQ Math. Log. Q., **54 (3)**, (2008), 307–322. [MR2417803 (2009d:03120)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2417803),

and

> Arnold W. Miller. [**Descriptive set theory and forcing. How to prove theorems about Borel sets the hard way**](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/lecture-notes-in-logic/Descriptive-Set-Theory-and-Forcing--How-to-Prove-Theorems/toc/lnl/1235423343). Lecture Notes in Logic, 4. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1995. [MR1439251 (98g:03119)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1439251).

Here is a small sample of his results:

Given a separable metric space $X$, let its *Baire order* $\mathrm{ord}(X)$ be the least
$\alpha$ such that each Borel subset of $X$ is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ in $X$. For example, $\mathrm{ord}(\mathbb R)=\omega_1$, $\mathrm{ord}(X)=1$ if $X$ is discrete, $\mathrm{ord}(\mathbb Q)=2$, $\mathrm{ord}(X)\le 2$ for any countable metric space $X$.

The result that $\mathrm{ord}(X)=\omega_1$ whenever $X$ is uncountable Polish is due to Lebesgue. Mazurkiewicz asked to identify the ordinals $\alpha$ for which we can find an $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ with $\mathrm{ord}(X)=\alpha$, and Banach conjectured that if $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ is uncountable, then $\mathrm{ord}(X)=\omega_1$. (See *On the length of Borel hierarchies* for precise references.)

Kunen proved that Banach's conjecture fails in the strong sense that if $\mathsf{CH}$ holds, then for each $\alpha\le\omega_1$ with $2<\alpha$, there is an uncountable $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ with $\mathrm{ord}(X)=\alpha$. Miller improves this by showing that the existence of a [Luzin set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin_space) suffices for this result. He also proves that Banach's conjecture is consistent, and has results under Martin's axiom (for example, there are uncountable subsets $X,Y$ of the Cantor set with $\mathrm{ord}(X)=2$ and $\mathrm{ord}(Y)=3$).

It is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (without choice) that the Borel hierarchy on the reals has length $\omega_2$ (the relevant models are rather pathological. For example, $\omega_1$ must have countable cofinality). Miller also shows that for any limit $\alpha<\omega_2$ it is consistent that the Borel hierarchy of the reals has length $\alpha+1$. Assuming (significant) large cardinal assumptions, he further shows that for any $\lambda$ (no matter how large) it is consistent that the Borel hierarchy has length at least $\lambda$.

Comment: Hi, Andres. What's the large cardinal strength of the assertion in the very last sentence of your answer? Do you have a reference for this? Thanks.

Comment: @Moni145 Unfortunately, I don't know. In his "Long Borel hierarchies" paper, Miller obtains this result by forcing over Gitik's model where all (well-ordered) cardinals have cofinality $\omega$, but I do not know of any lower bounds. We also don't know what the consistency strength of Gitik's result is. Results of Busche and Schindler indicate it is at least the consistency strength of $\mathsf{AD}$, but this is very far from the current upper bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm taking a brief look at Miller's paper over here. You mention, and I see, that he assumes every well-ordered cardinal having cofinality $\omega$, but what is the large cardinal consistency strength of this?

Comment: That is the result I refer to at the end of my comment: Gitik used a proper class of strongly compact cardinals. To force any instance of Miller's result, we only need an initial segment of the cardinals to have cofinality $\omega$, and to arrange this, only a (set-sized) sequence of strongly compact cardinals is needed, following Gitik's method. But already one strongly compact cardinal is way beyond the region we currently understand with descriptive inner model-theoretic methods, and the best lower bound we have is, more or less, the strength of $\mathsf{AD}$.

Answer (score 7):

In

> Alexander S. Kechris, *Classical descriptive set theory*, Springer-Verlag, 1995

which is (one of) the classical reference for (classical) descriptive set theory, you find on page 168 the Theorem 22.4 which says

> For any uncountable Polish space, the Borel hierarchy is strict. That is for every countable ordinal $\xi$, $\mathbf{\Delta}^0_\xi \subsetneq \mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\xi \subsetneq \mathbf{\Delta}^0_{\xi+1}$.

In particular, this implies that for every uncountable Polish space $X$ and for every countable ordinal $\xi$, $\bigcup_{\alpha<\xi} \mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\xi \subsetneq \mathcal{B}(X)$.

Here, I assumed you are talking about boldface classes, eventhough you used lightface notations.