# In how many steps is it necessary to construct the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

We only consider Borel sets on $\mathbb R$. As we know, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is constructed transfinitely as follows:

1. Let $B_0=\mathcal T$ be the set of open sets on $\mathbb R$;
2. If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, $B_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}B_\beta$;
3. Otherwise, let $\beta=\alpha-1$, and $B_\alpha=(B_\beta)_{\delta\sigma}$, where $A_\delta$ denotes the collection of countable intersections of sets in $A$, and $A_{\delta\sigma}$ denotes the collection of countable unions of sets in $A_\delta$;
4. Let $\mathcal B=B_{\omega_1}$ where $\omega_1$ is the smallest uncountable ordinal, then $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

However, I wonder whether $\omega_1$ is the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $B_\alpha=\mathcal B$, i.e. the minimal step to finish the process. As we know, $((0,1)\cap\mathbb Q)\cup([2,3]\setminus\mathbb Q)$ is a Borel set which is neither $F_\sigma$ nor $G_\delta$.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, $\omega_1$ steps are needed. One way of seeing this is to note that the Baire hierarchy of functions requires $\omega_1$ steps (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/631755/462)), and each level can be characterized in terms of the Borel complexity of the preimages of open sets. One can also argue directly, in terms of universal sets. See Kechris's **Classical descriptive set theory**. On the other hand, without the axiom of choice, it is consistent both that the hierarchy is longer, and that it is shorter (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/511265/462)).